# C++ Stuck in Infinite Loop After Changing Something That has Nothing to do With Loop

Tags: c++, loops

I wrote this code and had it running fine, however there were some formatting errors so I changed some code and added an else if statement that I marked with a comment in the code.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

/*if (argc != 3) {
    cout << "Error: wrong number of arguments." << endl;
}*/

ifstream infile(argv[1]);
//infile.open(argv[1]);

string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

string final;
string temp;
string distinct[5000];
string look;
int distinctlen = 0;
int distinctnum[5000] = { 0 };
int numdist = 0;
int wordcount = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
int quest = 0;
int isdistinct = 0;
int ismatch = 0;
int qmatch = 0;
int len = content.length();
bool wordprinted = false;
//cout << "test 1" << endl;
//cout << "length of string: " << len << endl;
//cout << "content entered: " << content << endl;
while (i < len) {

    //cout << "test 2" << endl;
    if (isalpha(content[i])) {
        //cout << "test 3" << endl;
        if (isupper(content[i])) {
            //cout << "test 4" << endl;
            temp.push_back(tolower(content[i]));

        }
        else {
            //cout << "test 5" << endl;
            temp.push_back(content[i]);

        }
    }
    else {
        //cout << temp << endl;
        //cout << "test 6" << endl;
        ++wordcount;
        final = final + temp;
        j = 0;
        for (k = 0;k < numdist;k++) {
            //cout << "test 7" << endl;
            if (distinct[k] == temp) {
                ++distinctnum[k];
                isdistinct = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isdistinct == 0) {
            //cout << "test 8" << endl;
            distinct[numdist] = temp;
            ++numdist;
        }
        temp.clear();
        isdistinct = 0;
    }
    //cout << temp << endl;
    ++i;
}
//cout << final << endl << endl;
cout << "The number of words found in the file was " << wordcount + 1 << endl;
cout << "The number of distinct words found in the file was " << numdist + 1 << endl << endl;

ifstream infile2(argv[2]);
string query((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile2)),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
//cout << query << endl;
query += ' ';

int len2 = query.length();
int looklen;
//cout << quest << endl;
for (i = 0;i < len2;i++) {
    if (query[i] == '?') {
        quest = 1;
    }
    else if (isspace(query[i])) {
        //cout << "test1" << endl;
        if (quest == 0) {
            //cout << "test2" << endl;
            for (j = 0;j < numdist;j++) {
                if (look == distinct[j]) {
                    ismatch = 1;
                    cout << look << " : matches " << look << " " << distinctnum[j]+1 << " time(s)." << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (ismatch == 0) {
                cout << look << " : no match." << endl;
            }
            ismatch = 0;
        }
        else {
            //cout << "test" << endl;
            looklen = look.length();
            //cout << looklen << " " << look << endl;
            for (j = 0;j < numdist;j++) {

                for (k = 0;k < looklen;k++) {

                    //cout << k << endl;
                    if (looklen < distinct[j].length()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (look[k] == '?' && (k + 1) == looklen && wordprinted == false) {
                        cout << look << " : matches " << distinct[j] << " " << distinctnum[j] + 1 << " time(s)." << endl;
                        k++;
                        wordprinted = true; //NEW LINE ADDED
                        cout << "wordprinted = true" << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (look[k] == '?' && (k+1) == looklen && wordprinted == true) { //NEW CODE ADDED THAT BROKE IT
                        for (i=0;i < looklen;i++) {
                            cout << " ";
                        }
                        cout << "   ";
                        cout << "matches " << distinct[j] << " " << distinctnum[j] + 1 << " time(s)." << endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (look[k] == distinct[j][k]) {
                        k++;
                    }
                    else if (look[k] == '?') { //check for space
                        k++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if (look[k] != distinct[j][k]) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if ((k + 1) == looklen) {
                        //cout << "test3" << endl;
                        cout << look << " : matches " << distinct[j] << " " << distinctnum[j] + 1 << " time(s)." << endl;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
            wordprinted = false;
            cout << "wordprinted = false" << endl;
        }
        look.clear();
        continue;
    }
    look.push_back(query[i]);
    //cout << "test" << endl;
    cout << len2 << endl;

}
return 0;
```

}

A slight excerpt from the output I'm getting:

> wordprinted = false
>   22
>   wordprinted = false
>   22
>   22
>   22
>   wordprinted = false
>   22
>   22
>   22
>   a?? : matches and 4 time(s).
>   wordprinted = true
>         matches as 1 time(s).
>         matches a 1 time(s).
>   wordprinted = false
>   22
>   wordprinted = false
>   22
>   22
>   22
>   wordprinted = false
>   22
>   22
>   22
>   a?? : matches and 4 time(s).
>   wordprinted = true
>         matches as 1 time(s).
>         matches a 1 time(s).

Comment: For everyone else who might have trouble finding the new `if`, search for this line : `else if (look[k] == '?' && (k+1) == looklen && wordprinted == true)`

Comment: You are supposed to ask a question.

Comment: Your example is too long and it's unclear what you expect this function to do versus what it is actually doing. You will have to simplify your example and clarify the expected and observed behavior. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information on producing a helpful example.

Answer (score 2):

You reused the `i` index inside the new code. Which resets the counter from the outer loop each time. Gotta be careful with nested for loops.

One way you can avoid that is to stop declaring the counter variables at the top of the program. Declare them inside the for loop's header, always:

```
for(int i=0;i<len2;i++)
```

Then the compiler would have alerted you that you reused a counter variable. Try and minimize the scope of variables and instantiate them in set circumstances such as the above. Globals and reusing variables for multiple purposes is especially bad. Anonymous counters like 'i' are ok, but declare them with the specific scope they make sense for.